# Google Indexing Logo Warping

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, favicon

I've recently published my company's site with Cloudflare, etc. The logo given to me was given as an svg. Google has started making the site available to searches however the logo appears to be warped with a solid white background.

[image: Warped Logo]

The favicon shows up perfectly however the search site:soulsoftware.org returns this warped mess. Is there anything that I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would ditch the svg.  And make sure your favicon is square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your svg favicon appears to be 246px wide and 729px tall. It appears that Google is stretching it to fit the standard favicon square. To avoid the stretching, you'll want to size your svg so that it has a square view box (canvas).

The white background is more difficult to diagnose, but my hunch is that Google simply does not support svg favicon transparency. To fix this, you would want to use a different file format for your favicon, such as `ico` or `png`. You can use a program such as Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator (or an online tool, I'd imagine), to render the `svg` to a `png`.

Note that svg favicons are [not compatible with Safari](https://caniuse.com/link-icon-svg) and tend to have poor compatibility with other non-browser software, so I wouldn't recommend them in general. I don't see them a lot in practice.